# Is there any real number except 1 which is equal to its own irrationality measure?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Is there any real number except $1$ which is equal to its own [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)? If so, then what is the cardinality of the set of all such numbers? Is the set dense on any interval? Is it measurable?

Comment: If $x$ has irrationality measure $\mu$, and $y$ has irrationality measure $\tau<\mu$, does $x+y$ automatically have irrationality measure $\mu$? Linguistically, I'd want this to be true. It seems like it might be helpful.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249194/irrationality-measure-of-the-number-is-itself

Answer (score 19):

Using the property stated in that article:

$$\mu(x)=2 + \limsup \frac{\log a_{n+1}}{\log q_n}$$

where the continued fraction expansion for $x$ is $[a_0,a_1,...]$ and the $n$th convergent is $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

Start with $a_0=2$ and $a_1=2$, so $q_0=1$, $q_1=2$.

Now, assume you have a continued fraction
$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}=[a_0,...,a_n]$$

Define $a_{n+1}$ to be the least integer such that $2+\frac{\log a_{n+1}}{\log q_n}>\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

Then $x = [a_0,a_1,...] = \lim \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ will satisfy your requirement.

Just show a bound on $2+\frac{\log a_{n+1}}{\log q_n}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

In particular, you can use that $\log (a_{n+1}-1)>(\log a_{n+1}) -1$ to show that if $2+\frac{\log a_{n+1}}{\log q_n}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}>\frac{1}{\log q_n}$, then $$2+\frac{\log (a_{n+1}-1)}{\log q_n}>\frac{p_n}{q_n}$$
which would violate our definition of $a_{n+1}$.  So $$\mu(x)=2+\limsup \frac{\log a_{n+1}}{\log q_n} = \lim \frac{p_n}{q_n}= x$$

So there exists such an $x$.

You can easily get uncountably many such $x$ by choosing any values $a_{2n}\in\{1,2\}$ and then choose the $a_{2n+1}$ by the above condition, again making the $\limsup$ equal to the limit of $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

I think the same argument can be made to show that the set is dense in $[2,\infty)$.  Basically, you can make such a $x$ starting with any finite sequence $[a_0,...,a_n]$ with $a_0\geq 2$.  Indeed, it is uncountable in any finite sub-interval $[a,b]$ with $b>a\geq 2$.

I don't think this resolves the measurability issue, contrary to my earlier claims.

It feels like $\{x:\mu(x)=x\}$ should be measurable, since it feels fairly constructive.  On the other hand, it feels like if the set $\{x:\mu(x)=x\}$ has non-zero measure, then $\{x:\mu(x)=x+\alpha\}$ should have non-zero measure, when $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, and thus we'd have an uncountable set of disjoint positive measures, which I believe is not possible.

So my guess is that the set is measurable with measure $0$.

But that is all gut, no proof.

Answer (score 3):

Just thinking out loud, this is not my area of expertise at all but I found the question intriguing. This should be a comment but it's too long.

Using $\mu$ for the irrationality measure, and since:
$$\begin{align}\mu(x)=1&\text{if}\ x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ \mu(x)=2&\text{if}\ x\in\mathbb{A}\text{ [Roth]}\\ \mu(x)\ \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}\ \infty&\text{if}\ x\ \text{is Liouville}\\ \mu(x)\geqslant2&\text{otherwise} \end{align}$$ then $1$ is the only rational or algebraic number satisfying your condition. So any possible solution must be: (1) transcendental, (2) $>2$, and (3) not a Liouville number. Unfortunately we only know (or have upper bounds on) the irrationality measures of a very few such numbers and none of them work, and there are uncountably many transcendental numbers that are not Liouville.

There *is* a construction method for numbers $x$ that have a given $\mu$, namely $$x = [\lfloor a\rfloor;\lfloor a^b\rfloor,\lfloor a^{b^2}\rfloor,\lfloor a^{b^3}\rfloor,\dots]\ |\ a>1,b=\mu-1$$ See [Brisebarre, 2002](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem01-02/brisebarre.ps&ei=QZL-TtOUEsfXgQfW7uTxCQ&usg=AFQjCNGr3TTYIqEOp6leYPgNq08JApoX6A&sig2=8ujM4kVCqQa0Xydhk6lNvA). So I suppose one could set $x=\mu$ and work from there. But I don't find that anyone has done so, yet.

Comment: Nice observation. If the function $x(\mu)$ is continuous, I guess then we might be in business. :-)

Comment: The question of the continousness of $\mu(x)$ is fascinating. Its value is discontinuous ($\infty$) for all Liouville numbers, but since the Lebesgue measure of the Liouville numbers is $0$, I suppose it's nevertheless possible that it's a continous function. If anybody would want to undertake this question, I understand that Roth won the Fields for that kind of thing. :)

Comment: I mean, possible that it's a differentiable function, of course.

Comment: Oh, I did not mean the continuity of $\mu(x)$; my apologies if that wasn't clear. It is clearly discontinuous because it is $1$ at every rational number and $\geqslant 2$ elsewhere. What I meant was the continuity of the number $x(\mu)$ whose irrationality measure $\mu$ (where $x(\mu)$ is regarded as a function of $\mu$).

Comment: Ah, I see. But of course we can construct an infinite number of $x$'s given any particular $\mu$.

Comment: That is a good point, but easily redeemed. Precisely, I am asking whether such a number can be continuously defined; i.e., does there exist a continuous function $x : [2, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that for all $\mu \geqslant 2$, $x(\mu)$ has irrationality measure $\mu$.